# apply the whole template or template parts depending on the condition

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the template

```
<xsl:template match="node" mode="some_mode">
    <xsl:value-of select="child1" />
    <xsl:value-of select="child2" />
    <xsl:value-of select="child3" />
</xsl:template>
```

I want to apply the template so it would select all the nodes specified in the template in one case like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="some_node" />  <!-- select all inside the node tag  -->
```

and in another case I want to limit the output and for example not to select <child1> or <child2> nodes. Can I do it with a variable or a param? Or do I have to write another template from scratch?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="some_node" />  <!-- select only some tags from the node tag  -->
```

In other word I will use this templates several times and I want to contorl the output when applying. I can define the variable, but the documentation says that I can't change the value of a variable once it was defined. Probably the param will wrok but I'm not good with it.

Comment: This question is really vague. It would help a lot if you could provide a simple example of a simple input document, your expected output, and an explaination of the rules in the example transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible without modification of the template you have. 
You could think about storing template output in a variable and then processing it to remove `child1` and `child2` values. But I guess you would be unable to guess which part of your output is coming from `child1` and/or `child2`.

Or you can develop another template that performs that alternative action.

EDIT: Another idea:

Maybe it is possible to apply filtering to get rid of `child1` and `child2` before applying your template (that would be a sort of multi-pass XSL tranformation).

Comment: You are pobably right, but this is really sad when I have a long template I use several times, and jsut want to limit its output in some cases

Comment: I think you are right, I can exclude the unnecessary tags when applying template. Thanks!

Comment: Your comment is exactly my answer as given below! The if instruction excludes tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [xsl:if](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_if.asp) instruction inside your template to branch.

Example:

```
<xsl:template match="node">
  <xsl:value-of select="child1" />
    <xsl:if test="price &gt; 10">
      <xsl:value-of select="child2" />
      <xsl:value-of select="child3" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I was hoping for a simple example in the question. As of the face-of-it one is not forthcoming, I'll make up a simple example here, which emodies your question, and show you how the xsl:if instruction is the perfect answer.

Let's say you have a music collection like so ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>

        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>

        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>

</catalog>
```

And you want to output a html table of your CD's listing title and price. Normally you want both title and price, but on some conditions (say price is less than $10), you want to suppress the output of price, and just have some static text in its place, like "cheaper than 10.00".

So your expected output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
    <td>cheaper than 10.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hide your heart</td>
    <td>9.90</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The style-sheet to produce this transformation could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//cd"/>
        </table>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="cd">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <xsl:if test="price &lt; 10">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="not(price &lt; 10)">
            <td>cheaper than 10.00</td>
          </xsl:if>
        </tr>
      </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And there you have the perfect answer - how to apply the whole template or just parts of it depending on a condition. In this case the condition is that the price is less than $10.

Comment: I want to limit the ouptut within xsl:apply but not inside this template

Comment: But this does limit the output within the apply! Maybe we are not talking the same language? A simple example is needed.

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry for my English. I know how to use xsl:if, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend using separate templates with different match patterns and/or in different modes**. This is to be preferred to using conditionals and thus writing messy and potentially buggy code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="allChildren"/>
==========
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="child3Only"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node" mode="allChildren">
   <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node" mode="child3Only">
   <xsl:copy-of select="child3"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following document** (similar to the one you used in a previous question):

```
<document>
    <node>
        <child1>Child 1</child1>
        <child2>Child 2</child2>
        <child3>Child 3</child3>
    </node>
    <anotherNode />
</document>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<child1>Child 1</child1><child2>Child 2</child2><child3>Child 3</child3>
```

==========

```
<child3>Child 3</child3>
```

Comment: I know it would be better, but consider that this template is 200 lines long and it has to be used 3 times, each time excluding only a couple of elements, so it would take longer to process 3 different templates than to try to exlclude what I don't need. I still didn't find the answer though It would be great to write somehing like <xsl template select="node[not(some_child_node)]" mode ="somemode"/>

Comment: @tylik: Your big problem that you haven't provided any meaningful example/problem. I suspect that your *real* problem has a very simple and efficient solution. You need to learn how to ask good questions. Try again.

Comment: Hm, probably you are right, but you gave me the answer on my question. I need to be able to sort out some nodes within <xsl:apply-templates /> so it would select all nodes inside parent node except for the ones specified within select like this <xsl apply-templates select="prentNode[not(some_child_Node)]" /> If you are interested in marking your answer as the right one, I will do it if you can provide the right xpath expression

Comment: @tylik: Please, edit the question, provide a specific (doesn't have to be long) xml document, provide the exact wanted answer, *explain* the rules for the transformation. Then you would have a question and many people would be able to give you a good solution.